# Immutable.js algorithm: List.update_or_add(item)

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I want to concatenate 2 lists in immutable.js.

Both lists have this structure: { id, value }

The algorithm concatenate should do this:

- If an ID exists in both list1 and list2 take the value from list2.

```js
let list1 = [
    { id: 1, value: 'foo' },
    { id: 3, value: 'bar' },
    { id: 2, value: 'baz' },
]

let list2 = [
    { id: 1, value: 'quux' }, // id 1 exists in list1
    { id: 4, value: 'asd' },
]

let result = [
    { id: 1, value: 'quux' }, // from list 2 
    { id: 3, value: 'bar' },
    { id: 2, value: 'baz' },
    { id: 4, value: 'asd' },
]
```

If Immutable.js has this functionality with another type (eg. Dictionary), I could also use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Algorithms for union**

First you have to maintain two map with key as `id` and value as `object` then check for length of array which is of bigger size and pass the bigger size array with small size map to `merged` function there you can iterate over the array and check if it's exists in the map if yes then update the object and delete that row from map otherwise add the object into output. After the for loop complete check if map has element present then push all the values from map into output array and return;

index.js

```
const old = [
  { id: 1, value: 'foo' },
  { id: 3, value: 'bar' },
  { id: 2, value: 'baz' },
];

const newa = [
    { id: 1, value: 'quux' }, // update
    { id: 4, value: 'asd' }, // push

];

 function merged(input,filterMap){
     var output = [];
      input.forEach(function(eachRow){
                        if(filterMap.hasOwnProperty(eachRow.id)){
                 output.push(Object.assign(eachRow,filterMap[eachRow.id]));
                 delete filterMap[eachRow.id];
              }else{
                  output.push(eachRow);
              }
                });

          if(Object.keys(filterMap).length > 0){
            output = output.concat(Object.values(filterMap));
          }
          return output;
 }

function parseData(first,second){
   var mapFirst = {},
       mapSecond = {};
   var output = [];
   first.forEach(function(eachRow){
            mapFirst[eachRow.id] = eachRow;
        });

   second.forEach(function(eachRow){
                    mapSecond[eachRow.id] = eachRow;
   });

   if(first.length > second.length){
        return merged(first,mapSecond);
   }else{
     return merged(second,mapFirst);
   }
}

console.log(parseData(old,newa));
```

Working jsFiddle demo - https://jsfiddle.net/qz25hnmf/